# ctrl click class in Eclipse shows binary / jar instead of source

Tags: android, eclipse

Using Eclipse
Version: Helios Service Release 2
Build id: 20110218-0911

with Android plugin. I have an Android project "AndroidUtil" that is marked as a "library" project for my main Android application.  When I ctrl + click the name of a class defined in AndroidUtil, I am taken to the binary / jar version of that class instead of the source file.  How can I make it take me to the source instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you control-click and it displays the class file editor in the editor pane, you should see an "Attach Source" button. Click that and point it to the library project in your workspace.

Comment: I don't see any "Attach Source" button.  Where does it appear?  What does it look like?

Comment: In the "Class File Editor" that opens in the editor pane, there will be a section that says "Source Not found" near the bottom of that section will be a grey "Attach Source" button.

Comment: I don't have "Source Not Found".  The editor looks exactly like my source code, comments and all.  I'm guessing that means that the editor knows where my source is.  So why is it opening the class instead of the source?

Comment: I understand now: it is taking you to the class file since your project depends on the library jar and not the other project in your workspace. You could add the other project as a dependency in your build path and then on the "order and export" tab reorder it so it appears before the jar and then eclipse should take you where you want

Comment: Issue and fix confirmed for:

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Indigo Service Release 1
Build id: 20110916-0149

with ADT, Android Development Toolkit
Version: 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534

Comment: For a fix, please star:  
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23685&q=eclipse%20source&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Comment: that's rigth: build path and then on the "order and export" tab reorder, tnks!

Answer (score 0):

For those with a newer version of the SDK, it might help to check out the workaround in this thread http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23685