# What does Post invalidate method do in Thread class

Tags: multithreading, android-custom-view, java-threads

This is my code:

```
package com.example.analogclock;

    import android.view.View;


public class MyThread implements Runnable {

    private View view;

    public MyThread(View v){
        view = v;
    }

    public void run() {
        while(true){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                view.postInvalidate();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I think Ctrl+ left click will take you to the method and you can then see what it does.

Comment: Thanks but after pressinf Ctrl+left click I get that defination                 public void postInvalidate() { /* compiled code */ }                                  what does that mean now ... I dont understand ...

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5521596/2196341

Comment: As for the Ctrl + click not showing you the code. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8261321/2196341